# Replacing all values from 4 columns in "|" seperated file using AWK in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have a | separated file and want to replace columns 2, 4, 6, 7  dates from 20200929 to 20201007.

File: e.lst

```
1|20200929|mni|20200929|pqr|20200929|20200929
2|20200929|mni|20200929|abc|20200929|20200929
3|20200929|mni|20200929|lmn|20200929|20200929
4|20200929|mni|20200929|stu|20200929|20200929
```

Command I tried is working for 2 columns.

```
awk -F\| '{OFS=FS}$2=20201007, $4=20201007 {print}' e.lst > ne.lst
```

But the same command when I add more columns to it, it gives a syntax error.

```
awk -F\| '{OFS=FS}$2=20201007, $4=20201007, $6=20201007 {print}' e.lst > ne.lst
                                          ^syntax error
```

Comment: Good answer below, OR you can use `;` (semi-colons) instead of `,` (commas). Good luck.

Comment: if other columns cannot have a match, you can also use `sed 's/20200929/20201007/g'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk` to assign same value to multiple columns in a single expression:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} { $2=$4=$6=$7=20201007 } 1' e.lst > ne.lst

1|20201007|mni|20201007|pqr|20201007|20201007
2|20201007|mni|20201007|abc|20201007|20201007
3|20201007|mni|20201007|lmn|20201007|20201007
4|20201007|mni|20201007|stu|20201007|20201007
```

Comment: one more I want in this scenario is the changes we are making should exclude header and trailer records. please help with same.

Comment: Your sample doesn't have header/trailer records. Skipping head row is each by using `NR > 1 { $2=$4=$6=$7=20201007 }` but skipping trailing records is not that simple. Can you please post a new question with sample data so that we can help you better

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Have created an `awk` variable `new` which has your new date value, so we need not to change code inside, tomorrow you want to change it to a new value then change it here itself.

```
awk -v new="20201007" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$2=$4=$6=$7=new} 1' Input_file
```

***Why OP's code didn't work:*** `awk` works on logic of `condition` then `action`, since OP wants to simply assign values to fields there is NO scope of condition here(until/unless OP don't want to hard code the field values), so OP is trying to assign values to fields but NOT in correct manner. It should be inside `{.......}` and it should be separated by equal to NOT by `,`. Hence it would become like `{$2=$4=$6=$7=your new value}`